# Navmenu to display different text with css when hovering

Tags: css, html-lists

For the bilingual website I have been building I'd like to have certain menu links show the English translation when hovering on the link before clicking it.

I know it can be done with the before and after values in css but so far I have been unsuccesful.

Here's the bit of css

```
#navmenu {
    font-family:'Sugo';
    letter-spacing:1px;
    font-size:2em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align:center;
    position: relative;
}

#navmenu ul {
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    list-style-type: none; 
    list-style-image: none; 
}

#navmenu li {
    display:inline;
}

#navmenu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 4em;
}

#navmenu li a:hover{
    color: #fff;
}

#navmenu li:nth-child(1) a:hover {
    background: #ffa83c;
}

#navmenu li:nth-child(2) a:hover {
    background: #ffa83c;
}

#navmenu li:nth-child(3) a:hover {
    background: #ffa83c;
}

#navmenu li:nth-child(5) a:hover {
    background: #ffa83c;
}

#navmenu li:nth-child(6) a:hover {
    background: #ffa83c;
}

#navmenu li:nth-child(7) a:hover {
    background: #ffa83c;
}
```

and this is the bit of html that is causing the issues.
it would seem there are too many classes fighting each other but disabling them is not really an option.

```
    <div id="navmenu">
<div class="menu-dutch-container">
<ul id="menu-dutch" class="menu">
<li id="menu-item-1764" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1764">
<a href="http://www.hellodolly.be/info/" class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-not-hovered">INFO</a>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-4021" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4021">
<a href="http://www.hellodolly.be/index/" class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-not-hovered">INDEX</a>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-6654" class="zoek menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-6654">
<a href="http://www.hellodolly.be/zoek.php" class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-not-hovered">zoek</a>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-3857" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-3857">
<a href="http://www.hellodolly.be" class="menu-image-title-hide menu-image-not-hovered">
</li>
<li id="menu-item-3973" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3973">
<a href="http://www.hellodolly.be/nlemail/" class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-not-hovered">EMAIL</a>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-3964" class="policy menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3964">
<a href="http://www.hellodolly.be/beleid/" class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-not-hovered">BELEID</a>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-6552" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-6552">
<a href="http://more.hellodolly.be" class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-not-hovered">EXTRA</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Ideally, for instance, the word "zoek" should transform to "search" upon hovering, same makeup.

Any thoughts as how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I would put the text in a `<span>zoek</span>` and the english text also in span with the class english. Or whatever class you want to indicate that you want to show that text.

Hide the span with the class english.
When you hover over the `<a>` hide the spans, but show the english text.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/wn0Ld47e/ (hover over "zoek")

Comment: Hi, I have added the span classes in the arry function in header.php, and included the extra css.

However, all menu items now display "searchpolicy" when hovering, while only "zoek" should become "search" and "beleid" "policy".

Is there a way to make them specific in the array funtion ?


<div id="navmenu">
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 
'theme_location' => 'header-menu',
    'link_before'   => '<span>',
    'link_after'    => '</span><span class="search">search</span><span class="policy">policy</span>'
 ) ); ?>